# Find results based on maximum date in sql

Tags: t-sql

I am trying to get the results for the maximum date and in the existing table structure, have date split into three columns (day, month and year). I am looking for the best approach to tackle this as the sql at the bottom works but I am not sure if I should be writing a statement like that?

```
Table Structure "blah"

    ID GUID,
    Description varchar(max),
    Column - Day (Stores Day of the Month),
    Column - Month (Stores Month of the Year),
    Column - Year (Stores Year)

    SELECT Count(ID), Description, MAX(CONVERT(DATE,CAST([Year] AS VARCHAR(4))+'-'+
                        CAST([Month] AS VARCHAR(2))+'-'+
                        CAST([Day] AS VARCHAR(2))))
    From blah
    Group by Description
```

However, the above statement also brings a couple of records that are not max.
Now I have another way of doing this and it works but not sure if that is the best way which is following:

```
SELECT Count(ID), Description, CONVERT(DATE,CAST([Year] AS VARCHAR(4))+'-'+
                    CAST([Month] AS VARCHAR(2))+'-'+
                    CAST([Day] AS VARCHAR(2))) As [Date]
From blah
Group by Description
Having CONVERT(DATE,CAST([Year] AS VARCHAR(4))+'-'+
                    CAST([Month] AS VARCHAR(2))+'-'+
                    CAST([Day] AS VARCHAR(2))) = (SELECT MAX(CONVERT(DATE,CAST([Year] AS VARCHAR(4))+'-'+
                    CAST([Month] AS VARCHAR(2))+'-'+
                    CAST([Day] AS VARCHAR(2)))) From blah)
```

Comment: Aside: DDL is more useful than some vague clues about a table's structure. `Column - Month (Stores Month of the Year)` might have a value like `'August'`? `Column - Day (Stores Day of the Year)` might be `'Christmas'`? Is there a reason not to include a day of the _month_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understood the problem very clearly because your explanation and your attempted code say different things

If you are looking for just one row which is the the row against the maximum Date, then you can write like this:

```
SELECT   * 
FROM     blah
WHERE    DATEFROMPARTS (Year, Month, Day) = (SELECT MAX(DATEFROMPARTS (Year, Month, Day)) FROM blah);
```

If you rather need the the same for each Description, then:

```
;WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT   Description, MaxDate = MAX(DATEFROMPARTS (Year, Month, Day))
    FROM     blah
    GROUP    BY Description
)
SELECT  *
FROM    blah B
        INNER JOIN CTE 
           ON B.Description = CTE.Description 
           AND DATEFROMPARTS (B.Year, B.Month, B.Day) = CTE.MaxDate;
```